# How to add action/link in SharePoint 2013 Search result for Edit/View Document Library Item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-property, sharepoint-search

I am working with SharePoint 2013 Search and is working fine.

I am looking for a way to add link/action which will redirect user to edit/view page of document.

By default result is having document url and clicking on the link open the document.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

I followed below steps,

1. Add ListItemID managed property to SharePoint result
2. Edit Display Template with below JavaScript and HTML

   var viewDocumentUrl = ctx.CurrentItem.ParentLink;
   viewDocumentUrl = viewDocumentUrl.replace("AllItems.aspx","")
   var viewDocumentHtml = String.format('View Property', viewDocumentUrl, ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID);

   var editDocumentUrl = ctx.CurrentItem.ParentLink;
   editDocumentUrl = editDocumentUrl.replace("AllItems.aspx","")
   var editDocumentHtml = String.format('Edit Property', editDocumentUrl, ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID);

Comment: If the document is in a folder, then the ParentLink property will link to that folder.  Also, if the default view isn't AllItems.aspx, the string replace won't work.